# Kotlin set field issue with varargs

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code where I am using Spring's SimpleMailMessage to prepare an email.

```
    val message = SimpleMailMessage()
    message.from = "myemail@gmail.com"
    message.to = "email@togo.com"
    message.subject = "subject here"
    message.text = "email body here"
```

The compliler is complaining about the message.to line claiming that val cannot be reassigned.
I have noticed that the setTo method in SimpleMailMessage accepts varargs of String and found a workaround with using message.setTo(email).

Is that a known issue or am I missing something ? Thanks

Comment: Java setters that take a vararg have no Kotlin property analog, so they cannot be treated like properties. This is normal.

Comment: Couldn't the Kotlin compiler be configured to work like that?

Comment: Maybe, but then what should the getter return? If I had to guess they don’t support vararg properties because the semantics don’t really fit the concept of a property and the syntax would be confusing.

Comment: I think it would make sense the compiler to create 2 setters, one for String and one for String[]. Currently, even this doesn't work ( message.to = arrayof("email@togo.com") )

Comment: Kotlin doesn't support overloading property setters whatsoever even though setter method overloading is common in various languages. I haven't dug into the reasons behind them choosing not to support that. It might be that they are considering adding union/intersection types someday in the future, which would be the natural solution to this problem, but it's low on the todo list.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin can only convert Java setters to property syntax if they take exactly one argument. In this case, `setTo` takes a vararg argument, so it won't be automatically converted. You could make an extension property to work around this:

```
var SimpleMailMessage.to: String
  get() = ...
  set(value) = setTo(value)
```